# Stack rank increasing by itself in TFS (Kanban)

Tags: tfs, kanban

I'm having a weird issue in my TFS user stories (Kanban). The stack rank are apparently increasing automatically, as if the user is doing it (see screenshot).

Why does it happen and how can I disable this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a result of moving user stories on the Backlog tab. Each time you drag and drop a user story up or down the backlog, its Stack Rank gets updated automatically to reflect its change in priority related to other user stories.

Comment: I understang what you're saying, but it isn't exactly what is happening. Nobody in the team are changing priorities so frequently as the log says. Maybe it can happen in response to another user stories being created with smaller ranks or changing priority (triggering a kind of chain reaction). Does it make sense?

Comment: TFS organize the priorities automatically when new items being pushed to the backlog. In any case, the trigger is a person who changed or added a user story. You can trace it by the records of the name and the time of the change.